# VB.NET, MySQL & Crystal Report comparative statement between two tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

My two MySQL tables have different information but one field is common. I am showing you the structure of two tables.

[image]

I need to show it in a single report filtering by `cust_id`.

i.e. Customer Id wise billing and payment report.

I tried...

`SELECT * FROM billing_info as a,payment_info as b WHERE a.cust_id='1' AND b.cust_id='1' AND a.cust_id=b.cust_id`

but rows are repeating.

Hope I explained this properly. Now what should I do ?

Is it possible in `Crystal Report` to show two tables data ?

Comment: Try using `Distinct` in SQL Query

But you should use `INNER JOIN` to get better result.

Comment: `SELECT billing_info.id AS ID, .... FROM  billing_info INNER JOIN tblpayment_info ON billing_info.cust_id = payment_info.cust_id where billing_info.cust_id=payment_info.cust_id`

Comment: Hi @Mahadev , I tried as per your instruction, but rows are repeating. My query is like `SELECT DISTINCT billing_info.cust_id as cust_id, billing_info.bill_no AS bill_no,billing_info.bill_dt AS bill_dt,billing_info.bill_amt AS bill_amt, payment.pay_date as pay_date,payment.pay_amt as pay_amt FROM bill INNER JOIN payment ON billing_info.cust_id = payment.cust_id where billing_info.cust_id=payment.cust_id AND billing_info.cust_id='1' AND payment.cust_id='1'`

Comment: is it necessary to put cust_id in both tables ?

Comment: @Mahadev no, it is not necessary.

Comment: Ok then, Keep cust_id in one table and and use that tables Primary_key in another table as foreign key and then try above query. E.g. Suppose billing_info has a Primary_key named Billing_ID. Now remove cust_id from payment_info and replace it with Billing_ID. Keep cust_id in billing_info

Comment: But Customers are not paying bill wise. How can I understand that it is a payment of customer no# 1 or 2. For your information, id in payment_info is incremental.

Comment: How are these two tables related ? What is a scenario here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78416/discussion-between-raj-and-mahadev).

Answer (score 0):

I guess ur table structure may resulting duplicate entries.

in table payment_info instead of using the cust_id (reference of cust table),  u should use id of table billing_info so that we will get more precised output for ur query. 
U also get payment details agains which bill has been made.

Comment: Sorry **SanG**, Customers are paying randomly, not bill wise.